# How to detect Flash version with PHP or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, flash, version, detect

I'd like to store the flashversion of users of a website in a database, so when they report problems with the website I can easily see which flash version they use. Is there a way to detect it with PHP or with javascript?

Comment: See this [webpage](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/11/20/detecting-flash-player-version-with-javascript/).  It appears to do what you want.

Comment: Travis' link looks like the most simple way – or you can use this: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: Big tutorial: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html

Answer (score 1):

AS3 replaced AS2's patchy `getVersion` with the [flash.system.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class.  There you will find a property called version that will give you what you want.  It's not *in* Javascript or PHP, but a small (and possibly invisible) SWF can easily send a get request to a server page to post the information to your database.

If you *need* the request to be done in Javascript, for some reason, it is possible (although not fluid) to have AS3 and Javascript communicate.